# Would our child have four nationalities?

Tags: united-kingdom, netherlands, belgium, nationality, multiple-citizenship

I (f) am a dual citizen of Netherlands and Belgium, born in Netherlands. I only hold a Dutch passport but I have all rights to apply for a Belgian passport. My husband is a UK citizen. We are considering moving to the USA. What would the nationality of a child born there be?

I assume he or she would have all four nationalities at least till the age of 26, where the child would lose Dutch and/or Belgian nationality if they haven't lived there or applied for a passport. Is my assumption true or am I missing any rules? Does the fact that I don't hold a Belgian passport make a difference?

Comment: I do realise it would not matter much in practice, since there's 3 EU nationalities involved, but I am curious nonetheless.

Comment: Uk, us and nl nationality seems alright, not sure about the Belgian, they have some weird laws, as you have to both born in Belgium and have a Belgian parent, otherwise you have to do some paperwork

Comment: The Dutch nationality loss would occur at 28, not 26, but can be postponed for 10 years by living in the Netherlands (including the Caribbean parts of the Kingdom) or the EU for at least one year, by getting a passport, ID card, or nationality certificate, by being in the foreign service of the Kingdom or one of its constituent countries, or of an international organization to which the Kingdom belongs, or by being the spouse or partner of someone in such service.

Comment: Not an answer, but relevant: [the Council of Europe's Convention on the Reduction of Cases of Multiple Nationality](http://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/rms/090000168006b659)

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/4460/do-any-countries-allow-most-cases-of-dual-citizenship-yet-somehow-restrict-trip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They would have **three** citizenships automatically, although you would need to do the paperwork to register them in all the countries.  More specifically, all children born in the US are Americans (with some rare exceptions for diplomats etc), and all children born to Dutch or UK nationals inherit those citizenships as well.

**Belgium** would be the exception here, since they do not grant citizenship automatically to children both outside Belgium. Their nationality law is convoluted, and we'd need to know your place and date of birth to give an accurate answer, but as you yourself were borrn outside Belgium, most likely you would have to apply to register your child within 5 years of birth. This in turn would require some clear evidence that you're a Belgian citizen: not necessarily a passport, mind you, but that would likely be the easiest option.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgian_nationality_law