# Which countries limit the number of citizenships their citizens may have to 3?

Tags: multiple-citizenship

[Nomad Capitalist's "How many citizenships can one person have?" video](https://youtu.be/SraT_jtpZc4?t=128) claims that:

> There are some countries [...] that say 3 [citizenships] is the max.

Which countries limit the number of citizenships their citizens may have to 3?

Comment: Have you asked at Nomad Capitalist how the number was ascertained?

Comment: This is related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/4460/do-any-countries-allow-most-cases-of-dual-citizenship-yet-somehow-restrict-trip?rq=1 and indicates that Uganda is the only known case of a country allowing two (but not three) citizenships.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica yes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SraT_jtpZc4&lc=UgyaJUntT14FkbrQkGx4AaABAg sorry I wish I could link in the question the other places where I asked the question but typically I'm eating downvotes and negative comments because of it (notably on http://travel.stackexchange.com/), so sometimes I simply don't. Thanks, your link seems to answer my question!

Comment: An explicit limit “you can have three citizenships but not four” would be strange. I could imagine it as an indirect consequence, like “you can have our citizenship, and inherit a citizenship from your father, and one from your mother”.

Comment: @gnasher729 Good point. Or maybe for some historical reason (e.g. something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_nationality_law_and_Hong_Kong) that resulted in some inhabitants getting 3 citizenships.